# Pass constructor call on to other class

Tags: java, javafx

I have a generic class that generates an UI and a subclass that shoud generate a more specialized version of this class.
The thing is, that the superclass is also called generically from multiple locations, so basically I would have to decide in the superclass weather the superclass should handle the call or "pass it on" to the child class.

```
public class AddEntryWindow<T extends SomeUiClass>
{

    public AddEntryWindow(TableDefinition tableDefinition, RefreshListener refreshListener)
    {
        // regular init stuff

        if(T == PartUiClass) // I know this doesn't work like this
        {
            return new AddPartWindow(tableDefinition, refreshListener);
            // I know this doesn't work either.
        }
    }
}


public class AddPartWindow extends AddEntryWindow<PartUiClass>
{

    public AddPartWindow(TableDefinition tableDefinition, RefreshListener refreshListener)
    {
        // (usually super would have to be called here)

        //special init stuff
    }
}
```

The call looks like this:

```
new OpenBlockingWindowHandler(scene, new AddEntryWindow<T>(TableDefinitionGenerator.getTableDefinitionByClass(elementToSelect), this)));
```

Is such a construction somehow possible in java?
Is it somehow possible to let a constructor "return" another classes instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is such a construction somehow possible in java? Is it somehow
>   possible to let a constructor "return" another classes instance?

No, a constructor can never return an instance of another class. Actually adding *any* return statement to a constructor is considered a syntax error in Java.

> The thing is, that the superclass is also called generically from
>   multiple locations, so basically I would have to decide in the
>   superclass weather the superclass should handle the call or "pass it
>   on" to the child class.

You could add a static factory method to the class, that accepts the runtime class of the type parameter as an argument. Something like this:

```
public static <T extends SomeUiClass> AddEntryWindow<T> createAddEntryWindow(TableDefinition tableDefinition, RefreshListener refreshListener, Class<T> c){
    if(PartUiClass.class.isAssignableFrom(c)){
        return (AddEntryWindow<T>) new AddPartWindow(tableDefinition, refreshListener);
    }
    return new AddEntryWindow<>(tableDefinition, refreshListener);
}
```